# Title box in tikz pgfplot showing wrong RGB color?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have the following graph:

[image]

created by the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h] 
\caption{Time series median of APE based on combinatorial selection schemes}
\label{Figure.TimeseriesofAPE}
\centering 
\begin{tikzpicture}   
\begin{axis}[width=14cm,height=8cm,
            ylabel={Absolute Percentage Error},
            xmin=2003.5,
            xmax=2018.5,
            ymin=15,
            ymax=35,
            xtick=data,
            xticklabel style=
            {/pgf/number format/1000 sep=,rotate=40},
            ytick={15, 20, 25, 30, 35},
            axis background/.style={fill=gray!5},
            legend style={fill=gray!5},
            xtick pos=lower,ytick pos=left,
            yticklabel=\pgfkeys{/pgf/number format/.cd,fixed,precision=0,zerofill}\pgfmathprintnumber{\tick}\%,
             title=\fcolorbox{black}{rgb:red,0;green,48;blue,133}{\makebox[12.2cm]{\textcolor{white}{\textbf{EV/EBIT}}}},
             title style={yshift=-0.34cm},
]
            \addplot [semithick,mark=square*,black,mark options={scale=1.2}] coordinates {
(2004,23.9477345892197)
(2005,24.0195465335992)
(2006,20.6276481251735)
(2007,18.265284388086)
(2008,21.8111180034732)
(2009,24.2629967323528)
(2010,22.2193898469998)
(2011,23.4662001690915)
(2012,22.3983479598189)
(2013,21.6518435739983)
(2014,20.7295962241899)
(2015,21.5151016657556)
(2016,22.728213671688)
(2017,20.6614535846647)
(2018,23.2079687708666)


    };
\addlegendentry{SBP Plus SARD}
\addplot[semithick,mark=*,red,mark options={scale=1.2}]
coordinates{
(2004,30.6453384436133)
(2005,25.9071572285215)
(2006,21.5368656549373)
(2007,23.1619489291921)
(2008,22.716278332465)
(2009,26.6295451295127)
(2010,25.7656563953101)
(2011,21.0579081996823)
(2012,23.9734983213042)
(2013,27.0328903793312)
(2014,23.5204904251705)
(2015,24.5540581415406)
(2016,27.393772936285)
(2017,23.77644107908)
(2018,24.9426613487672)

    };
\addlegendentry{GICS Plus SARD}    
            \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Now, I have specified the RGB as: `Red=0, Green=47, Blue=135`. However, this color seems quite off, as I use the same RGB specification for my chapter and section headings, which looks like:

[image]

which has the RGB specification, as `0,47,135`. What is going on?

Comment: Did you try a color picker?

Comment: Yes, I did in Powerpoint. The result for the title box is: Red=0, Green=66, Blue=189.

Comment: Nice question. I just checked and got 0-68-187, which is not so different from yours.

Comment: My best guess is, the values you give for the `rgb` option are not the classical values in range [0, 255], but parts of the total sum of all these values. In your case all three add up to 182, which gives 0% red, 25.8% green and 74.2% blue. Converting that back into the [0,255] range gives 0, 66, 189, which are exactly the values you get in the color picker.

Comment: Can you also add code that produces the sections headings? It might be a problem of different colour models

Comment: My color picker tells me that your box has the background color `\definecolor{obscureblue}{RGB}{39, 70, 182}`, and using `title style={yshift=-0.34cm,fill=obscureblue,text
    width=12.2cm,text=white,font=\bfseries,align=center},
             title=EV/EBIT,` reproduces it. BTW, please replace `\documentclass[article]` by `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}` to have a working document.

Comment: I put in your suggestions, thank you. However, your color picker saying its obscure blue with different RGB is kind of an issue, I don't see how one can change the RGB format, since it is merely between 0 and 255?

Comment: Can you also add code that produces the sections headings? It might be a problem of different colour models

Comment: If I change the document class to `book` and add `\usepackage{titlesec}\definecolor{obscureblue}{RGB}{39,70,182}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\normalfont\Huge\bfseries\color{obscureblue}}
  {\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{20pt}{\Huge}` to the preamble and `\chapter{Discussion}` to the body of the document, I get consistent coloring.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason why users on this site tend insist on complete minimal working examples is because otherwise there is a good chance that we waste a lot of time because it is not clear how you obtained the result. How did you get the result? A chapter in a an article document. Anyway, this is something that produces consistent coloring.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\definecolor{obscureblue}{RGB}{39,70,182}
% borrowed from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/1477/121799
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\normalfont\Huge\bfseries\color{obscureblue}}
  {\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{20pt}{\Huge}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Discussion}
\begin{figure}[h] 
\caption{Time series median of APE based on combinatorial selection schemes}
\label{Figure.TimeseriesofAPE}
\centering 
\begin{tikzpicture}   
\begin{axis}[width=14cm,height=8cm,
            ylabel={Absolute Percentage Error},
            xmin=2003.5,
            xmax=2018.5,
            ymin=15,
            ymax=35,
            xtick=data,
            xticklabel style=
            {/pgf/number format/1000 sep=,rotate=40},
            ytick={15, 20, 25, 30, 35},
            axis background/.style={fill=gray!5},
            legend style={fill=gray!5},
            xtick pos=lower,ytick pos=left,
            yticklabel=\pgfkeys{/pgf/number format/.cd,fixed,precision=0,zerofill}\pgfmathprintnumber{\tick}\%,
             title style={yshift=-0.34cm,fill=obscureblue,text
             width=12.2cm,text=white,font=\bfseries,align=center},
             title=EV/EBIT,
]
\typeout{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/width}}
            \addplot [semithick,mark=square*,black,mark options={scale=1.2}] coordinates {
(2004,23.9477345892197)
(2005,24.0195465335992)
(2006,20.6276481251735)
(2007,18.265284388086)
(2008,21.8111180034732)
(2009,24.2629967323528)
(2010,22.2193898469998)
(2011,23.4662001690915)
(2012,22.3983479598189)
(2013,21.6518435739983)
(2014,20.7295962241899)
(2015,21.5151016657556)
(2016,22.728213671688)
(2017,20.6614535846647)
(2018,23.2079687708666)


    };
\addlegendentry{SBP Plus SARD}
\addplot[semithick,mark=*,red,mark options={scale=1.2}]
coordinates{
(2004,30.6453384436133)
(2005,25.9071572285215)
(2006,21.5368656549373)
(2007,23.1619489291921)
(2008,22.716278332465)
(2009,26.6295451295127)
(2010,25.7656563953101)
(2011,21.0579081996823)
(2012,23.9734983213042)
(2013,27.0328903793312)
(2014,23.5204904251705)
(2015,24.5540581415406)
(2016,27.393772936285)
(2017,23.77644107908)
(2018,24.9426613487672)

    };
\addlegendentry{GICS Plus SARD}    
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the contribution, that solved the issue! However, I noticed that the class of the document works with the article document type as well.